# Grok pattern for Timestamp in the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok, grok

Need a grok patter to satisfy this format of timestamp
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
sample : 2021/11/11 05:04:11

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Where are you using this grok pattern? In Logstash, in Elasticsearch ingest pipelines, in Filebeat, elsewhere? Help us help you!

Comment: https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns

Comment: Hi Val, I am using this in ingest node pipeline present in kibana UI

Comment: Hi Arman, Nothing in that page matches my date pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a custom pattern to define date as I could not find any pre-existing for this date.This works in ingest node pipeline present in Kibana UI

%{MYPATTERN:datetime}%{SPACE}

Definition of mypattern :

```
{
 [1-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}
}
```